# hclust() - Error in hclust(d) : object 'C_hclust' not found in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Trying to call the `hclust()` function in R, and I am getting the following error:

```
library(stats)
d <- dist(as.matrix(mtcars))
hc <- hclust(d)
```

`Error in hclust(d) : object 'C_hclust' not found`

Not sure what is the issue as other functions from the "stats" library work, such as dist (used above)

Comment: Are you using Renjin (Java interpreter)?

Comment: just checking - have you tried restarting your `R` session?

Comment: @LoveTätting I believe not (as I am not aware of what Renjin is)

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg - Yes I did.

Comment: They seem to not have ported that part of the c code yet to renjin. If you are not restricted to the jvm, try the official R interpreter and problem should be solved :-)

Comment: @LoveTätting, is the official R interpreter something I need to download? Or how do I make the switch?

Comment: You can find it at cran.r-project.org. I would suggest you install RStudio. It is an IDE that is easy to start using r in. There are many tutorials covering it.

Comment: I had no problem with your code... `C_hclust` is calling `.Frotran`. Did you try to reinstall `R` in your machine?